# if statement containing function not working in php

Tags: php

I have an if statement using password_verify function. The password_verify is working as expected but when in the if statement it is always evaluated as false.

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        // do something. I never get here
    } else {
        // Incorrect password
        echo 'Incorrect password!'  . password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)? "ok": "ko";//here the password verify works as expected - I get "ok"
    }
```

I'm new to php so I guess I'm building the if statement wrong. I checked on websites and a book how to implement it and the code looks the same so I'm struggling to figure out where I'm wrong.
I have the same issue on the following:

```
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // do something.
    } else { //do something else
}
```

the $stmt->num_rows > 0 is always evaluated as false; $stmt stores a query result having one record.

Any suggestion would be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PHP's password\_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `var_dump($_POST['password'], $password);` before your `if(password_verify(...));` statement.

Answer (score 2):

> The password_verify is working as expected but when in the if statement it is always evaluated as false.

It's actually the other way around - your `if` statement is fine, but `password_verify` is returning `false`, and the way you tried to *debug* that was wrong, misleading you.

To see why, try running this code:

```
function something_that_returns_false() {
    return false;
}

echo 'Some text that disappears? '  . something_that_returns_false() ? "It was true": "It was false";
```

You might expect this to print `Some text that disappears? It was false`, but instead it just prints `It was true`!

Why? Because PHP doesn't read this the way you think it would; it looks first at this bit:

```
'Some text that disappears? '  . something_that_returns_false()
```

First it runs `something_that_returns_false()`, gets `false`, and decides how to represent that as a string, which in PHP is an empty string. That gets concatenated to the string `'Some text that disappears? '` (so, we just have that original string).

Then it checks whether *that string* should be considered "true". In PHP, any non-empty string is considered "true" in such contexts, so it ends up running this:

```
echo true ? "It was true": "It was false";
```

Which of course will print `It was true`.

To avoid this, use parentheses around the part you want to be evaluated separately - it's a good habit to always do this when using the ternary operator (`a ? b : c`):

```
function something_that_returns_false() {
    return false;
}

echo 'Some text that disappears? '  . (something_that_returns_false() ? "It was true": "It was false");
```

Now it prints `Some text that disappears? It was false`, which is more useful.

More simply, to test the value of something, you can use [var_dump](https://php.net/var_dump), which shows the exact value of the expression.

In your case:

```
var_dump( password_verify($_POST['password'], $password) );
```

You will find that this prints `bool(false)`, because somewhere you've got the use of `password_verify` wrong. See [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/157957) for some things to look at next.

Comment: it's actually always a good habit to wrap ternary in brackets if it is part of something more complex as I faced so many oddities otherwise, sometimes really hard to nail. just because of ternary and no brackets

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yeah, I thought of saying that, but couldn't quite decide how to word it, and the answer was already getting quite long.

Comment: many thanks for the explanation. the var_dump returned false as u guessed, and var_dump($stmt->num_rows) returns null, so my issue is not even the password_verify but the query I run which somehow doesn't retrieve data as expected - in phpmyadmin it works but not in php